# Tomcat cant run war

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, kotlin, war

I downloaded demo webapp from https://start.spring.io/ (gradle kotlin project).
Added 2 controllers for '/' and '/test' just to test if everything is OK.
Here is the code:

```
@Controller
class IndexController {

@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("/")
fun main() : String {
    return "Hello World"
}



@Controller
class TestController {

@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("/test")
fun main() : String {
    return "test"
}
```

Then i added war plugin to gradle

```
apply plugin: 'war'
```

Then i print to terminal

```
gradlew build
```

and in build/libs found .war file.
I deployed it to locat Tomcat, but

```
http://localhost:8080/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/
http://localhost:8080/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test
```

respond with 404 error.

In IDEA i can easy start my app and see Hello World and test.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[JAR file]**

You are missing imports in controller.

put below imports in your controller.

```
package com.example.demo

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
```

now remove the plugin `apply plugin: 'war'` and build project using `gradlew build`

it will create a jar file inside **app_name\build\libs**

open this location in command prompt and run below command.

```
java -jar <jar_file_name>.java
```

open application using below url.

```
http://localhost:8080
```

**[WAR file]**

extend SpringBootServletInitializer as below

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication : SpringBootServletInitializer()
```

put the plugin `apply plugin: 'war'` and build project using `gradlew build`

now inside **app_name\build\libs** it will create a war file.

deploy this war to tomcat server and access using below URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/
```